# Can HTML5 localstorage be accessed from a Windows Forms App?

Tags: .net, winforms, html

I have a web application that creates and stores data in HTML5 localStorage. Can a Windows Forms application running on the same client access this storage?

The Web application will be accessed only through IE9.

Comment: What do you want to see happen when the user has two browsers installed, and has used your web application with both?

Comment: @hvd The application will only be accessed from IE

Comment: IE doesn't support IndexedDB: http://caniuse.com/indexeddb. support will be added in IE 10. So you cannot use IE and have a web site storing something into this database simply because the client doesn't support it.

Comment: @Fahad You may want to update your question to include that, and also include which IE version and how your exactly web application is storing data. It significantly changes your question.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 database is a browser implementation detail. So the way to access this database might be possible but it would depend on which browser was used to access the web application.